# Using Boost Graph Library: property_map in boost::mutable_queue

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to instantiate a simple version of [boost::mutable_queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/pending/mutable_queue.hpp) with a custom `Node` type that I've defined.  I have no trouble instantiating a `mutable_queue<double>` instance using the following snippet (using std and boost namespaces, and all needed includes):

```
int N = 100;

mutable_queue<double> *q = 
    new mutable_queue<double>(N, less<double>(), identity_property_map());
```

However, when I try to switch `double` to `Node` (for which I've overloaded `operator<` and `operator==`), I'm no longer able to get it working.  Here's one representative example of what I'm trying:

```
typedef Node entry_t;
typedef vector<entry_t> storage_t;
typedef less<entry_t> comp_t;
typedef identity_property_map prop_map_t;
//typedef iterator_property_map<storage_t, 
//  property_map<storage_t, entry_t>::type >  prop_map_t;
typedef mutable_queue<entry_t, storage_t, comp_t, prop_map_t> queue_t;

queue_t *q = new queue_t(N, comp_t(), prop_map_t());
```

This gives me errors along these lines:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::mutable_queue >, std::less, boost::identity_property_map>::push(Node*&)’
    mutable_queue.h:100: note: candidates are: void boost::mutable_queue::push(const IndexedType&) [with IndexedType = UnitTest::Node_test()::entry_t, RandomAccessContainer = std::vector >, Comp = std::less, ID = boost::identity_property_map]
```

My suspicion is that I'm not understanding how to use `property_map`.  Could somebody help me fix this snippet, and maybe give a little explanation for why it's the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're calling push, but it appears that you're pushing a Node* when you should be pushing a Node:

```
::push(Node*&)
```

it's telling you there's a push for Node const&:

```
push(const IndexedType&)
```

where IndexedType = Node